# How to remove extra padding in matplotlib when zero spacing is already specified

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use constrained layout or tight layout in matplotlib, I always find strange extra white space on the left and bottom edge of the axes even though zero padding is specified. See below for a simple example. Is there a way to remove such white space?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def example_plots(fig):
    x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, 30)
    y = np.sin(x)
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.plot(x, y, '^-', mfc='w')


def tight_layout():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2,2))
    example_plots(fig)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    fig.savefig('tight_layout.pdf')


def constrained_layout():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2,2), constrained_layout=True)
    fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(wspace=0, hspace=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)
    example_plots(fig)
    fig.savefig('constrained_layout.pdf')


tight_layout()
constrained_layout()
```

[image: Extra padding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so experienced with constrained layout but I guess it's allocating ticks space even if you are not drawing them.

Setting the tick length to zero might work, not sure if is there a better solution:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_yticklabels([]) 
ax.tick_params(length=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But the spacing still persists after specifying `ax.tick_params(length=0) `, do you have any other idea what might leads to this?

Comment: @gthink weird, works perfectly here... Could be something you're doing in the `example_plots` function?